# Crear macro en VBA con script de SAP

Tags: excel, vba, script, macros

Intento crear una macro que coja datos de excel, busque en SAP y los devuelva a excel.Al crear la script en sap  (SAP solo me permite archivo VBS) hago corta-pega del archivo y lo pego en el módulo en VSA a continuación de la macro preparada para copiar la celda del dato a tratar en sap, y una vez lo ejecuto me da error en lo copiado del script.
Desconozco si al ser diferente tipo de archivo radica ahí el problema al ser diferente “idioma” de archivo.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.